# Not able to send email from Lambda to SES from within a VPC

Tags: lambda, amazon-vpc, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email from Lambda to SES.

When I run Lambda in NO VPC mode then email is successfully sent.

**But when I assign my VPC it doesn't work.**

AWS has VPC endpoint to connect to S3. It same available for SES? Or it is not possible to do so?

Comment: I've used SNS (which has VPC endpoint) to publish to a topic that triggers a lambda outside the VPC. You can send a SES json from your VPC lambda and let your lambda outside sends the mail in a reaction of a topic.

Comment: Thanks Vinicius. But this isn't the option I would prefer. FYI couldn't implement this as NAT is expensive for such a small requirement.

Answer (score 2):

VPC Endpoint is **only** available for S3 *currently*, there is plans to roll it out to other services already in flight but not available yet.

As Mentioned the VPC your lambda attaches to must have a route to the internet to connect to SES, the security groups must also allow the traffic to the secure SMTP port.

Comment: PrivateLink is available for SES as of Apr. 2020, but I haven't been able to get it to work. [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/)

Comment: Neither have I using the SES endpoint :( I attempted to connect a lambda to a serverless RDS, which has to be on a VPC - that worked. I attempted ot send an email from lambda - that did not. Set up SES endpoint and SMPT creds - smpt worked from local, but failed on the lambda via the ses endpoint. Support was not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In 2020 this is now [possible](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-simple-email-service-ses-for-vpc-endpoints/) by creating a VPC endpoint for SES (for the security group part just enable all traffic with the source being the security group the lambda belongs to).

However, as far as I can tell you cannot send mail using the SES API, you have to use SMTP. I set up my lambda as follows:

```
"use strict";
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "email-smtp.YOURREGION.amazonaws.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.USER,
      pass: process.env.PASS,
    },
});

const SENDER = 'no-reply@domain.com';
const RECEIVER = 'to@domain.com';

const response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    "body": "{\"result\": \"Success.\"}"
};

const errResponse = {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "headers": {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
    "body": "{\"result\": \"Failed.\"}"
};

exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    transporter.sendMail({
        from: SENDER,
        to: RECEIVER,
        subject: "Hello ✔",
        text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>", // html body
    }, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(errResponse, null);
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info);
            callback(null, response);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Lambda doesn't have Internet access. I'd confirm the Lambda subnet is associated with a route table that has a route to the internet (the SES endpoint is on the public internet) — 0.0.0.0 should point to a NAT gateway (or equivalent to outbound route to the internet).

Comment: so since aws hasnt provided with ses endpoint just like it did for s3, then i have to create nat gateway even though lambda is launched in public vpc with security group outbound set for internet?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me in a similar situation was to use SNS to invoke another lambda that is not inside a VPC to call the SES service.
You can create an endpoint for SNS and connect it to the VPC.